# How do I know if this limit even converges?

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

So, there is this question which I found quite new according to my experience, and it is as follows.

> Assuming that interchange of limit and integration is permissible, evaluate the following: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} {\int_0^1 \frac{nx^{n -1}}{1 + x}dx}, \quad 0 < x < 1$$

Now, I first tried integration by parts, and it doesn't give me more than an expression which is also nearly impossible to evaluate (maybe I'm doing it wrong, though) -

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{1}{1+x}\int nx^{n - 1}dx  +  \int\frac{x^n}{(1 + x)^2}dx\right|_0^1$$

I'm not sure how to proceed from there, so I tried this instead:

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} {\int_0^1 {nx^{n - 1}(1 + x)^{-1}}dx}$$

Expanding $(1 + x)^{-1}$ using Taylor Series:

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} {\int_0^1 {nx^{n - 1}(1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + x^4 - x^5 \ldots)}dx}$$
> $$ = \lim_{n \to \infty} {\int_0^1 {(nx^{n - 1} - nx^n + nx^{n + 1} - nx^{n + 2} + nx^{n + 3} - n^{x + 4} \ldots)}dx}$$
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{n}{n+1} + \frac{n}{n+2} - \frac{n}{n +3} + \frac{n}{n +4} - \frac{n}{n + 5}\ldots\right)$$

I think that diverges. Then, I tried putting the expression in Desmos and increased the $n$ value slowly upto $500$, $1000$ and similar big numbers - which all returned values around $0.5$.

The question was an multiple-choice based and there were both of them listed as options.

I'm not sure who is correct, the calculator, or me.

It would be a huge help if someone looks into this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: +1 for writing up the question with great context.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You're welcome :D

Comment: You should see that the same technique applies to limit of $\int_0^1 nx^n f(x) \, dx$ when $f'$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ and the desired limit would be $f(1)$.

Comment: need more people like you , very nicely written +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK. Use integration by parts. Rewrite $I_n = \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \dfrac{d(x^n)}{1+x}= \dfrac{x^n}{1+x}|_{x=0}^1+ \displaystyle \int_{0}^1\dfrac{x^n}{(1+x)^2}dx= \dfrac{1}{2}+J_n$, and $0 \le J_n \le \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 x^ndx= \dfrac{1}{n+1}$. Hence $J_n \to 0$, and $I_n \to \dfrac{1}{2}$. So if you got $0.5$ then  you are right.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about the inequality we can use here :D

Though, why cannot we use the Taylor Series?

Comment: Yes you can, but you would have to work with an infinite series and you might end up using Abel's theorem and it's getting a little messy there.

Comment: Ah, that explains why I couldn't express the series I got in something simple.

Thanks again for your help, I was stuck with this for days XD

Comment: Sure, my pleasure.

Comment: @ODETutor Just a quick comment. The original question seemed to require that you interchange the limit and the integral to solve the problem. Notice that $$\frac{nx^{n-1}}{x+1}\longrightarrow \frac{\delta(x-1)}{x+1}$$ for $0<x<1$, where $\delta$ is the delta$-$dirac function. Therefore $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_0^1\frac{nx^{n-1}}{x+1}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\delta(x-1)}{x+1}dx=\frac{1}{1+1}=\frac{1}{2}$$ You can see more about handling integrals containing the delta$-$dirac function here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function

Comment: @MatthewPilling: Ah yes, this is quite advanced technique which is great. But I assumed that OP wanted to take the elementary route instead. Also, the Delta-Dirac function you mentioned is perhaps for use in a research article or graduate physics level as it is rarely mentioned in a standard undergraduate level math course. But there might be some exception such as OP class where his teacher allows to use this function.

Comment: You way is way better, I just don't how else to handle this situation if you're required to interchange the limit and the integral.

Answer (score 1):

*For your curiosity.*

$$I_n=\int n\frac{x^{n -1}}{1 + x}dx=n \left(\frac{x^n}{n}-\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \, _2F_1(1,n+1;n+2;-x)\right)$$ where appears the gaussian hypergeometric function.

Integrating between the bounds, this gives the simple
$$J_n=\int_0^1 n\frac{x^{n -1}}{1 + x}dx=1+\frac{1}{2} n \left(H_{\frac{n-1}{2}}-H_{\frac{n}{2}}\right)$$ Using the asymptotics of generalized harmonic numbers
$$J_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4 n}-\frac{1}{8 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method in the same spirit as a couple comments.  We trade off the use of integration by parts in favor of just using monotonicity of the integral.

Fix any $y$ such that $0 < y < 1$ and split the integral into two as
$$\int_0^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x}\,dx = \int_0^y \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x}\,dx + \int_y^1\frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x}\,dx$$

Then estimate each integral independently:

- On $0 \leq x \leq y < 1$, we have $0 \leq \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x} \leq nx^{n-1}$, so $$0 \leq \int_0^y \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x}\,dx \leq \int_0^y nx^{n-1}\,dx = y^n$$ and since $y^n \to 0$ we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^y \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x}\,dx = 0$$
- On $0 < y \leq x \leq 1$, we have $\frac{nx^{n-1}}{2} \leq \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x} \leq \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+y}$, so $$\frac{1}{2}(1 - y^n) = \int_y^1\frac{nx^{n-1}}{2}\,dx \leq \int_y^1\frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x}\,dx \leq \int_y^1\frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+y}\,dx = \frac{1 - y^n}{1+y}.$$  As once again, $y^n \to 0$, we have $$\frac{1}{2} \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int_y^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x}\,dx \leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \int_y^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x}\,dx \leq \frac{1}{1+y}$$

---

Putting it back in terms of the original integral, we've shown $$\frac{1}{2} \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x}\,dx \leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x}\,dx \leq \frac{1}{1+y}$$
which now only involves $0 < y < 1$ on the upper bound, and letting $y \to 1^{-}$ shows $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}$$

---

The other reason I mention this method is that it generalizes nicely.  We've used monotonicity of $\frac{1}{1+x}$ to keep everything clean, but even this is actually unnecessary.  The same argument may be made with any function $f$ which is continuous on $[0,1]$ (or even just $f \in L^{\infty}([0,1])$ which is left-continuous at $1$) to give $\int_0^1 nx^{n-1}f(x)\,dx \to f(1)$.

Comment: As with everyone else, I'm ignoring the "Assuming that interchange of limit and integration is permissible" part of the question.  Arguably, this is false on the level of functions and making such an assumption without introducing distributions would imply the limit is $0$ since $\frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x} \to 0$ for $0 \leq x < 1$ and the integral of $0$ is $0$.  Then again, if we make a false assumption, we're already inconsistent, so the value of the limit could then be arbitrarily chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x=t^{1/n}$ to obtain
$$
\int_0^1 {\frac{{nx^{n - 1} }}{{1 + x}}dx}  = \int_0^1 {\frac{{dt}}{{1 + t^{1/n} }}} 
$$
Now, since
$$
0 \le \frac{1}{{1 + t^{1/n} }} \le 1,
$$
we can apply the dominated convergence theorem to deduce
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \int_0^1 {\frac{{nx^{n - 1} }}{{1 + x}}dx}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \int_0^1 {\frac{{dt}}{{1 + t^{1/n} }}}  = \int_0^1 {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{dt}}{{1 + t^{1/n} }}}  = \int_0^1 {\frac{{dt}}{2}}  = \frac{1}{2}.
$$